# Draw a maze in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, maze

I'm making a random maze generator in Java. The user can select the algorithm and then press the "Generate" button to see the resulting maze in the center of the JFrame. Once the maze is generated i have to draw it inside a JPanel. If we consider the dfs with backtracking algorithm, for each cell i have 4 boolean variables indicating if the cell has a wall up, down, left, right.
The algorithm runs and removes these walls (Dream Theater \m/) accordingly. Now each cell should have the information needed to draw the maze but i don't know how to do. I can't play with the indexes to draw the lines.

This is a draft of the code:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(MAZE_PANEL_DIM, MAZE_PANEL_DIM,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g2 = image.getGraphics();
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, MAZE_PANEL_DIM, MAZE_PANEL_DIM);
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
for(int i = 0; i < Maze.DIM; i++) {          
    for(int j = 0; j < Maze.DIM; j++) {      // Note: the size of the cell is CELL_DIM = 600 / Maze.DIM
        Cell cell = cells[i][j];
        if(cell.hasRightWall()) {
            // draw vertical line on the right border of the cell
        }
        if(cell.hasDownWall()) {
            // draw horizontal line on the bottom border of the cell
        }
        if(cell.hasLeftWall()) {
            // draw vertical line on the left border of the cell
        }
        if(cell.hasUpWall()) {
            // draw horizontal line on the top border of the cell
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Ok, the solutions should be like this...

```
for(int i = 0; i < Maze.DIM; i++) {          
    for(int j = 0; j < Maze.DIM; j++) {      // Note: the size of the cell is CELL_DIM = 600 / Maze.DIM
        Cell cell = cells[i][j];
        if(cell.hasRightWall()) {
            // draw vertical line on the right border of the cell
            g2.drawLine(j * CELL_DIM + CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM, CELL_DIM + j * CELL_DIM, CELL_DIM + i * CELL_DIM);
        }
        if(cell.hasDownWall()) {
            // draw horizontal line on the bottom border of the cell
            g2.drawLine(j * CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM + CELL_DIM, j * CELL_DIM + CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM + CELL_DIM);
        }
        if(cell.hasLeftWall()) {
            // draw vertical line on the left border of the cell
            g2.drawLine(j * CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM, j * CELL_DIM, CELL_DIM + i * CELL_DIM);
        }
        if(cell.hasUpWall()) {
            // draw horizontal line on the top border of the cell
            g2.drawLine(j * CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM , CELL_DIM + j * CELL_DIM, i * CELL_DIM);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the right border and the bottom border don't get drawn.

Comment: What do you mean with `I can't play with the indexes to draw the lines.`?

Comment: I can't understand how to: g2.drawLine(?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Suppose you have a quad paper and a pencil. How would you do this by hand? How would you decide where to draw the lines on the paper?

Comment: Does that code correspond to each cell, or to the JPanel? Graphics2D.drawLine is documented actually in [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html). If I understand correctly, you want to paint the whole cell white, and the walls black with a line in case they are there, is that right?

Comment: That code is for the JPanel. I get all the cells of the maze (already solved) and i want to draw the walls of the maze iterating each cell. It is enough  draw the walls with black color.

Comment: You might want to read the JavaDoc of [`Graphics.drawLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Or is your issue with how you can calculate the coordinates you should specify as parameters?

Comment: Exactly, that's my issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) for the `Graphics` class say:

> The graphics pen hangs down and to the right from the path it traverses.

So if you are trying to draw the right-hand border of a cell on the right-hand edge of the maze, the `Graphics` pen will be outside of your `BufferedImage`.  The solution is to bounds-check the coordinates of the line segments and make sure all lines are drawn inside your image.

```
if (cell.hasRightWall()) {
  int fromX = j * CELL_DIM + CELL_DIM;
  int fromY = i * CELL_DIM;

  if (fromX >= image.getWidth()) {
    fromX = image.getWidth() - 1;
  }

  g2.drawLine(fromX, fromY, fromX, fromY + CELL_DIM);
}
```